# Auto continuous scrolling of man output

Tags: command-line, terminal, man

When I execute `man foo` the terminal shows only the first page and then pauses. Then I have to manually press the keys to scroll here and there.
After executing `man foo` how do I get an output which is continuously scrolling till the end of it. It'll be bonus if I could control the speed of scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man` itself does only call `$PAGER` to display the man page. `$PAGER` is usually set to `less`, which does not support such kind of scrolling.

You can simply set `$PAGER` to any other command that does support such a feature.

You can also simply do something like:

```
man man|perl -pe 'sleep 1'
```

Of course you can also make it sleep two seconds for each line. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
man 1 bash | 
  { clear
    for((i=0;i<LINES-2;i++)); do
      IFS= read -r line
      echo -e "$line"
    done
    sleep 5
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      sleep 1
      echo -e "$line"
    done; }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
man sed | col -bx | more
```

Or pipe it to `less` if you're a less guy. But, that should about do it to get out of the default controls of `man`.